# C# using already created AES key

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, aes

I have my pre generated AES key what i would like to use in C#. Can anybody point me to the right direction how to use pre generated AES key with `RijndaelManaged` object.

EDIT: I have the key in `byte[]` array and i need to encrypt a `Stream`.

I found these code samples online:

```
    private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] key, byte[] PGPkey)
    {
        RijndaelManaged rDel = new RijndaelManaged();
        rDel.Key = key;
        //rDel.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode.aspx
        rDel.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; // better lang support
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = rDel.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(PGPkey, 0, PGPkey.Length);
        return resultArray;
    }

    private static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] PGPkey)
    {
         RijndaelManaged rDel = new RijndaelManaged();
         rDel.Key = key;
         //rDel.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode.aspx
         rDel.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; // better lang support
         ICryptoTransform cTransform = rDel.CreateEncryptor();
         byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(PGPkey, 0, PGPkey.Length);
         return resultArray;
     }
```

Im not getting any errors but after decryption the byte array is not the same as it was before going to the ecryption.

EDIT: I think i got it working, had to set the `rDel.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;`

Comment: In which form do you have the key, and what do you mean by *pre generated* ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta, i have the key in byte[] array.

Comment: And do you need integrity checking?

Comment: No, i dont need integrity checking.

Comment: Don't use ECB. CBC is much better for your use. Your problem is most likely caused by not storing the IV with your encrypted data.

Comment: Does the CipherMode depends ont the key?

Comment: The cypher mode determines how the key is used to encrypt the data. Just read the wikipedia article:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation

Comment: Thanks! And u were right, i had the problem because i didnt store the IV. Now when i stored it and used it for decrypting everything worked allso in CBC mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it worked when setting it to `ECB` mode, that is becuase it was using `CBC` mode before, which uses a randomly generated Initialization Vector when encrypting. Initialization Vectors randomize the cipher text so two identical peiced of data, encrypted with the same key, dont produce the same cipher text. You can grab the `byte[] RijndaelManagedInstance.IV` property and store that with your cipher text. Then when decrypting, set the same property to the Initialization Vector used to encrypt, and then you should recieve the same plain text after decryption.

Answer (score 0):

You need the key as a `byte[]`. Then you assign it to the `Key` property.

For encrypting using the autogenerated IV is fine. But you need to store it with your encrypted data and put it into the decryptor to decrypt your data again.

Don't use `ECB`, `CBC` is a much better fit for your use.

Comment: Your question is too vague to tell you how to handle the IV. You didn't specify the encryption mode, nor if you're ancryting or decrypting.

Comment: That update doesn't help much. But I strongly recommend searching a high level crypto library that takes care of all that stuff for you.